# ThreadX porting on ARM development board

Tags: arm, porting, rtos, threadx

I've worked on Linux but i'm new to RTOS.
    I've following things:

1. Craneboard(AM3517) development board,below given link for that
2. Linux build for Craneboard
3. Application that runs on Craneboard
4. Downloaded ThreadX demo codes for AM3517

   - Now problem is that i want to install ThreadX(RTOS) on Craneboard and run demo code of ThreadX application on Craneboard.
   - I want to know that which IDE,toolchain can be used for for doing above thing.
   - How to build ThreadX for AM3517(Craneboard) ?

Craneboard : https://www.mistralsolutions.com/product-engineering-services/products/development-platforms/craneboard/

I'm new to ThreadX so need guidance.

Comment: you didnt get tech support when you bought threadx?

Comment: @dwelch..Actually I'm not aware about what support available when i purchase ThreadX.So I want to know what things will be provided with ThreadX purchase? and what i need to build?

Comment: then you call or otherwise contact their sales department and ask?

Comment: Ok..doing same thing.Waiting for their reply.I thought somebody has done work on that so i can get basic idea what things **ThreadX** vendor gives and what i  need to develop.

Comment: As Clifford pointed out directly or indirectly, a vendor like this is going to deliver a complete turnkey package.  ARM dominates the processor world (for every x86 you have several to dozens of arm based products), so there is no way they dont have an arm solution.  Now the turnkey package may be for a supported dev board and not necessarily the one you have, that is where you have to do the porting, but compiler, etc should be in there or a supported extra cost one should be an add on if that is how they do things.

Comment: If you were looking at chibios or freertos or linux or some other open source thing then sure, what tools do I need, etc to the general public is an understandable question.  Although many of the open source ones have examples and readmes or other that tell you what tools they use or you should try, and you should at least start by playing in their sandbox, maybe stay in their sandbox instead of building your own.

Answer (score 1):

Like most RTOS kernels, ThreadX is not "installed" on a board as you would a general purpose OS such as Linux.  Rather it is a object code library that you statically link to your application code and target run-time start-up to produce a single monolithic binary image that is executed directly on the board either from the reset vector or from some form of bootstrap.

As a commercial RTOS, you should seek guidance from the vendors documentation and technical support. ExpressLogic's site lists ARM RealView, IAR Embedded Workbench, Wind River Workbench, Keil, Green Hills, Lauterbach, MetaWare, EPI, and GNU as supported toolchains. There is an *AM3517 Experimenter Board* demo on [the ThreadX site](http://rtos.com/products/threadx/ARMThumb) that uses [IAR tools](https://www.iar.com/iar-embedded-workbench/arm/), which may be a good place to start, however since you are using a different board, the demo may require some adaptation.

Unlike Linux, support for most of the peripherals on your board will be down to you to implement; and RTOS typically provides scheduling, multitasking, inter-process communication, synchronisation and timing and little else.  File systems and networking etc. are normally add-on middleware at extra cost or from third-party sources.

Also unlike Linux, an RTOS cannot normally host its own development tools or debugger.  You require a cross-compiler and debugger and JTAG debug adapter.  I imagine that your board has a JTAG header, but since the site requires logging in to view the data sheet, I have not verified that.

Comment: @Clifford..this helps me a lot..still having some confusion...If i have AM3517 experimental board and building demo code gives me **am35xx_library.a**,then how to run sample code on AM3517 experimental board ?

Comment: Perhaps I should point out that I have never used ThreadX; my comments are either of a general nature or from publically available ThreadX documentation.  Chapter 6 of [the ThreadX User guide](http://rtos.com/images/uploads/ThreadX_User_Guide_V5.pdf) describes the standard demo.  A .a file is a GNU static-link library; presumably this is the ThreadX library? You need to compile the application code and link it with the ThreadX library.  In the case of the standard demo the source is in *demo_threadx.c*.  The linker will output fully linked object code.

Comment: ... Depending on your toolchain and device programming method you may have to generate a hex or raw binary file to program the device.